# This page isn’t working error when trying to loop in a Controller

Tags: laravel

I have a multiple checkbox option. I have a `foreach` loop to make my multiple check box.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{$employee->office_email}}">
```

Now When I am receiving the data in my controller using `$request->checkbox`I get the value in array obviously. But when I am trying to loop through the value I get `This page isn’t working` error.
Here is my code in my controller to loop for the array:

```
foreach ($request->checkbox as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
```

When I echo the `$key` in the loop I get the values of key.
Again I can access the values individually like this `$request->checkbox[0]`. But I can't access the values via a loop.
I have tried to loop the `$key` and access the values like this `$request->checkbox['$key']`. But get the error.
Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Try this `echo $value??""` ?

Comment: `dd($request->checkbox) ` and post what do you have in it...

Comment: @Bart This is the result of `dd($request->checkbox)`
`array:8 [▼
  0 => "nowrin@piit.com"
  1 => "rian@piit.us"
  2 => "asda@piit.us"
  3 => "<script type="text/javascript">alert('brrom')</script>@piit.us"
  4 => "<style type="text/css"></style>@piit.us"
  5 => "<!DOCTYPE html><html></html>@piit.us"
  6 => "Test_99@piit.us"
  7 => "ahanip@peoplentech.com"
]`

Comment: @C2486 I have tried that. Gives me the same error. If I `echo` the `$value` outside the `foreach(){}` loop I get the last value. So it means `foreach(){}` is working. I am just not being able to access the `$value` inside the loop.

Comment: OK! Solved the problem. Actually It was an security error. I had a script as name and I did not sanitize the input. So browser was giving me this error.